# If 'p-dataViewLayoutOptions' is an Angular component and it has 'layout' input, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular

I can't import DataViewModuleLayoutOptions in angular.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BGI.png)

in Angular version 15

Comment: please share code, not image of code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `[layout]="layout"` from `<p-dataViewLayoutOptions>`.

I encountered a similar problem when trying to set the default layout as 'grid'. This answer: [Dataview in primeNG is not getting displayed as grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63523240/dataview-in-primeng-is-not-getting-displayed-as-grid/68870663#68870663) helped me resolve it.

I moved `[layout]="layout"` to the `<p-dataView>` tag and added the following in the .ts file:

`layout: 'grid' | 'list' = 'grid'`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the `DataViewLayoutOptions` component has no `layout` input parameter according to the source code: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dataview/dataview.ts#L571-L573.

And `DataViewModuleLayoutOptions` module is not existing in `PrimeNg` repository.